# Why does Goku still train with King Kai?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

I don't get it. King Kai said he was no match against Nappa and Vegeta, but in Dragon Ball Super Goku is very eager to train with him despite King Kai having nothing else for him to learn.

Comment: iirc correctly, Goku was only training with him, not trained by him. King kai didn't teach him anything, just watched him training

Comment: I doubt Mohammed Ali's trainer was stronger than him, and yet he kept him as a coach.

Answer (score 9):

In King's Kai planet, he can train under 10 times gravity, plus King Kai can magically add weights of several tons to him like he did when he was training with him after being killed by Cell.

[image]

King Kai can also make big weight rings appear and many stuff like that

[image]